# Azure AD B2C Link to Sign Up Page (Not Sign In)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using Azure AD B2C with `msal.js` in my React app.

Currently, when the user tries to enter the protected area of my app, `msal.js` redirects the user to the login in page which provides a link to the sign up page.

Is there a way for me to send users directly to the sign up page? There are cases when I know the user has not yet signed up so it's bad user experience to send the user first to the sign in page then let them click and go to the sign up page. It would be nicer to just send them directly to sign up instead.

Comment: Hi Sam, did you follow Chris's suggestion to get around this? I've got the same issue and set up a separate sign up policy but the mixing of two authorities in msal seems to cause issues with the caching on tokens

Comment: @AndyM I gave up Azure AD B2C and implemented Auth0. I don’t think AAD B2C is ready for prime time yet. Chris does a great job answering questions but he’s one guy. Rest of the community or Azure AD team are not very helpful. Documentation isn’t very good and personally the user experience AAD B2C offers is horrible! That’s why I moved on.

Comment: thank you you coming back to me, I really appreciate it. To be honest I'm on the verge of ditching it as well there is certainly potential there but some of the limitations are show stoppers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure AD B2C Custom Policy with Sign Up Page Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497567/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-with-sign-up-page-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the sign-up or sign-in policy, you can [create a sign-up only policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy), which allows a new user to sign up with a local account and/or a social account.

Comment: With this approach upon sign-up a user will have to separately sign-in.

Comment: Hi @Sabel Are you referring to signing in in the same session or the next session?

Comment: My memory is a bit hazy at this second, but I believe that a sign up only policy will not authenticate the user automatically after sign up, only sign them up.