# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy with Sign Up Page Only

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to create a custom policy in Azure AD B2C. I can't find such an example in the [starterpack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack).

I checked this post [Azure AD B2C Link to Sign Up Page (Not Sign In)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196805/azure-ad-b2c-link-to-sign-up-page-not-sign-in) and, if I understand it correctly, there is no URL I can use for an existing custom `signup_signin` policy to end up directly in the Sign Up page. Creating "Sign up v2" flow works, but I need a custom one, and copying code from the build in one and placing it to the `LocalAccounts` example from the starterpack doesn't work.

This is the `UserJourney` code downloaded from "Sign up v2" flow

```xml
<UserJourney Id="B2CSignUp_V2"> 
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup"> 
      <ClaimsProviderSelections> 
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />           
      </ClaimsProviderSelections> 
    </OrchestrationStep>
  </OrchestrationSteps> 
</UserJourney>
```

I tried to replace the `OrchestrationStep` 1 and 2 from the starter pack with the one here but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Custom policies, In the B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase.xml file replace the 1st Orchestration Step for the User Journey Id="SignUpOrSignIn" with the following Orchestration Step and you will be directly landed to Signup page -

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: I did, but for some reason, it doesn't work, do you have any suggestion why it doesn't?

Comment: @Mustafamg It worked for me. Can you write which policy from the starter pack you used as a starting point.

Comment: This also worked for me, but I copied and pasted the existing SignUpOrSignIn Policy into a new SignUp policy (making sure to give it a unique PolicyId and PublicPolicyUri), and then in the TrustFrameworkExtensions, copied and pasted the UserJourney for SignUpOrSignIn, renamed it to SignUp, and performed the replacement for Step 1 suggested above.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can:

- Remove orchestration step 1
- Remove the **objectId** precondition from orchestration step 2
- Renumber the following orchestration steps

Such as:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
```

Comment: After following your comment I'm getting this error :
"B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS" of tenant "neogeo.onmicrosoft.com".User journey 'SignUpOrSignIn' in policy 'B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions' of tenant 'neogeo.onmicrosoft.com' has 2 sendClaims steps. Please specify a DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId attribute set to the default issuer technical profile reference id

Comment: There are 3 error actually. Here are the second two:
User journey "SignUpOrSignIn" in policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant "neogeo.onmicrosoft.com" has step 1 with 2 claims exchanges. It must be preceded by a claims provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be used.User journey "SignUpOrSignIn" in policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant "neogeo.onmicrosoft.com" has step 2 with 2 claims exchanges. It must be preceded by a claims provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be used.

Comment: Hi @user3090407. I've updated the above answer with all of the orchestration steps *after* following the alternate instructions. Do they match your orchestration steps?

Comment: Yes, this are the 3 steps I have. It works only if I have as a first step:
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
And Precondition for step 2