# B2C A sample of policy to perform a switch from a sign-up flow to a sign-in flow for existing user

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Microsoft page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/subjourneys#call-sub-journey mentions a scenario:

> Sign up to sign in: Consider a scenario where a user already exists in
> the directory but may have forgotten that they had in fact created an
> account. It may be desirable in such a case that instead of telling
> the user that the credentials they have entered already exists and
> forcing the user to restart the journey that the policy is able to
> perform a switch from a sign up flow to a sign in flow for that user.

However I wasn't able to find an example how to do it.
Is anyone implemented a switch from a sign up flow to a sign in flow for an existing user?
Any references will be appreciated.

I've asked the same question on MS Documentation repo [A sample of policy to perform a switch from a sign up flow to a sign in flow. #111047](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/111047)

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497567/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-with-sign-up-page-only   .Here Instead of creating signin , only signup flow is created.If you need the users to sign up check if it can do.